# How to ensure that my workitems are running parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

CL_DEVICE_NAME = GeForce GT 630

CL_DEVICE_TYPE = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU

CL_PLATFORM_NAME : NVIDIA CUDA

```
size_t global_item_size = 8;
size_t local_item_size = 1;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Here, printing in the kernel is not allowed. Hence, how to ensure that all my 8 cores are running in parallel?

**Extra info (regarding my question):** for kernel, i am passing input and and output array of 8X8 size as a buffer. According to workitem number, i am solving that row and saving the result in output buffer. and after that i am reading the result.

If i am running AMD platform SDK, where i add print statement in kernel by

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf : enable
```

hence i can see clearly, if i am using 4 core machine, my first 4 cores are running parallel and then rest will run in parallel, which shows it is solving maximum 4 in parallel.

But, how can i see the same for my CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU?

Any help/pointers/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you verifying that you have parallel execution by using `printf`?

Comment: @jprice sorry for late reply. printf is coming in random sequence for each 4 items. If i am running big function/loop in each workitem, printf sequence will be like (0,1,3,2,2,3,1,0,1,2,3,0.....)and if any first workitem is done then it will be replaced by next such as 4/5/... accordingly. Is this a proper approach?

Comment: @jprice and i am getting a speed up of around 3.5X for AMD platform. But for GPU, speedup varies. Hence i need to verify how many items are going in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `printf` is not at all a reliable method of determining if your code is actually executing in parallel. You could have 4 threads running concurrently on a single core for example, and would still have your `printf` statements output in a non-deterministic order as the CPU time-slices between them. In fact, section 6.12.13.1 of the [OpenCL 1.2 specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) ("printf output synchronization") explicitly states that there are no guarantees about the order in which the output is written.

It sounds like what you are really after is a metric that will tell you how well your device is being utilised, which is different than determining if certain work-items are actually executing in parallel. The best way to do this would be to use a profiler, which would usually contain such a metric. Unfortunately NVIDIA's NVVP no longer works with OpenCL, so this doesn't really help you.

On NVIDIA hardware, work-items within a work-group are batched up into groups of 32, known as a warp. Each warp executes in a SIMD fashion, so the 32 work-items in the warp execute in lockstep. You will typically have many warps resident on each compute unit, potentially from multiple work-groups. The compute unit will transparently context switch between these warps as necessary to keep the processing elements busy when warps stall.

Your brief code snippet indicates that you are asking for 8 work-items with a work-group size of 1. I don't know if this is just an example, but if it isn't then this will almost certainly deliver fairly poor performance on the GPU. As per the above, you really want the work-group size to be multiple of 32, so that the GPU can fill each warp. Additionally, you'll want hundreds of work-items in your global size (NDRange) in order to properly fill the GPU. Running such a small problem size isn't going to be very indicative of how well your GPU can perform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are enqueueing enough work items (at least 32 but ideally thousands) then your "workitems are running parallel".

You can see details of how your kernel is executing by using a profiling tool, for example Parallel Nsight on NVIDIA hardware or CodeXL on AMD hardware. It will tell you things about hardware occupancy and execution speed. You'll also be able to see memory transfers.